# setup maven project for java ee 7 (full profile) with eclipse (kepler-ee) and git

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, java-ee-7

So, now I have access to empty git repository (project development to start soon).
Eclipse is chosen IDE and maven as build tool, Glasshfish 4 as application server.

I have no problem using git via command line, outside eclipse, but it would be nice having complete setup within eclipse.

By the way, I've never used maven before, or Java EE, but I'm currently learning concepts and specs  for javaEE platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) (an Eclipse Git plugin) as a complement for the most common tasks. I used it a few years ago, had some issues, but the guys developed it quite actively so it should be mature for now.

As for Maven + Glassfish, I'd recommend reading a few tutorials like [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and [this for setting up the devenv](http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/13/hello-world-with-jsf-2-0-glassfish-3-maven-svn-and-eclipse/). Believe me, there are tons of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

well, here is what I have done in the end. Hope this is useful to someone else

Following this [tutorial](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1177/java/java-ee/maven/building-and-deploying-java-ee-ear-with-maven-to-java-ee-application-server-part-1-project-directory-structure-amp-module-generation-through-archetype-generate/) I've created maven directory structure for full Java EE 7 project (used java ee7 archetypes instead ee5 where applicable).

In root pom.xml I've added

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

so all modules will depend on java7.

I've copied this to git root folder, added .gitignore file for eclipse files.

In Eclipse, I've used import maven project. After that, right-click root project (eclipse will create multiple projects) folder and Team > Share Project > local git.

I guess only thing remaining for other devs beside import maven project after initial git pull (outside eclipse), is to configure java ee application server (Window > Preferences > Servers > Runtime Environments)